# MDX Parameter - SSRS

Tags: visual-studio, t-sql, reporting-services, mdx, business-intelligence

```
Parameter Value (It’s Unique Name) = [Company].[Company Hierarchy].&[10] 

Parameter Label (It’s Name) = HQ
```

I want to type in “HQ” and generate report for “[Company].[Company Hierarchy].&[10]”

So, basically, I want to TYPE in label text and transform that somehow so ssrs would generate report for it’s value that matches MDX format [dim].[hierarchy].&[member]

It's kind of hard to explain but how would I go about setting up the parameter and how would I use that parameter for datasets?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use `NameColumn` in `SSAS`.
If you properly set up your `Company` dimension, you will be able to reach your dimension via its name and not via its key.

`[Company].[Company Hierarchy].`**&**`[10]` *(that's the way you get the dimension with the key 10. The key 10 is unique, returning only one member)*

`[Company].[Company Hierarchy].[HQ]` *(that's the way you get the dimension with its name. `[HQ]` in this example might not be unique. Notice that I don't use **&** this time.)*